# Least present k-mers in the human genome

Tags: human-genome, sequence-analysis

What are the least present *k*-mers in the human genome at different sizes?

Starting with k=4 and going up in size until k=10, what are the *k*-mers least seen (or not at all) in the human genome? I am only interested in the reference human genome, so I am discounting SNPs/Indels in the population.

If this is not pre-calculated somewhere, what tool is recommended to use that starts with the *[GRCh38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_genome#Human_reference_genome)* reference as input?

Comment: If you are interested in least present k-mers, you might be interested also in the concept of minimum absent words (these two things are related). There are many papers on this topic, see, e.g.: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0029344. Another phrase to google is "word avoidance".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [Jellyfish](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21217122/) [software](http://www.cbcb.umd.edu/software/jellyfish) to calculate the k-mer profiles up to length 31.

From the instructions in the user [guide](http://www.genome.umd.edu/docs/JellyfishUserGuide.pdf):

The basic command to count all k-mers is as follows:

```
jellyfish count -m 21 -s 100M -t 10 -C reads.fasta
```

To compute the histogram of the k-mer occurrences, use the histo subcommand (see section 3.1):

```
jellyfish histo mer_counts.jf
```

To query the counts of a particular k-mer, use the query subcommand (see section 3.3):

```
jellyfish query mer_counts.jf AACGTTG
```

To output all the counts for all the k-mers in the le, use the dump subcommand (see section 3.2):

```
jellyfish dump mer_counts.jf > mer_counts_dumps.fa
```

Comment: I am trying jellyfish now.

Comment: I tried jellyfish, and got the list of kmers. But I couldn't get the list of kmers of count=0.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use R. I give you an example of only chr1 and only kmer=4.

```
library(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38)
library(Biostrings)

genome <- BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg38
kmers <- oligonucleotideFrequency(genome$chr1, 4)
kmers

m <- as.matrix(kmers)

m[order(m),]
```

Answer (score 4):

Grabbing chromosomes for `hg38`:

```
$ wget ftp://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/chromosomes/*.fa.gz
$ for fn in `ls *.fa.gz`; do gunzip $fn; done
```

Via [`kmer-counter`](https://github.com/alexpreynolds/kmer-counter) and Python, here's how to search for kmers of length 7 from chromosome `chrY`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

import sys
import subprocess
import itertools

k = 7
chr = 'chrY'
fastaFile = '%s.fa' % (chr)
kmerCmd = 'kmer-counter --fasta --no-rc --k=%d %s' % (k, fastaFile)

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(kmerCmd, shell=True)
    result = {}
    for line in output.splitlines(): 
        (header, counts) = line.strip().split('\t')
        header = header[1:]
        kmers = dict((key,int(val)) for (key,val) in [d.split(':') for d in counts.split(' ')])
        result[header] = kmers
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
    sys.stderr.write("%s\n" % (str(error)))

kmers = result[chr]
comp = {'A':'T', 'C':'G', 'G':'C', 'T':'A'}
for kmerList in itertools.product('ACGT', repeat=k):
    kmerKey = ''.join(kmerList)
    kmerCompKey = ''.join(reversed([comp.get(b,b) for b in kmerList]))
    if kmerKey not in kmers and kmerCompKey not in kmers:
        kmers[kmerKey] = 0

for key, val in sorted(kmers.iteritems(), key=lambda (key,val):(val,key)):
    sys.stdout.write("%s\t%s\n" % (key, val))
```

This script will print a two-column tab-delimited text file to standard output, where the first column is the 7mer and the second column is the count of that 7mer and its reverse complement over `chrY` (including zero-counts):

```
CGACGCG 20
CGTCGCG 20
CGCGATA 23
TACGCGC 25
...
AAATAAA 33521
TTTCTTT 34014
GAATGGA 35361
AATGGAA 36906
TTTTTTT 103093
```

With a couple tweaks, this script could run over a range of *k* and chromosomes for your reference genome.